# Snowflake - DATE_ADDDAYSTODATE function

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have encountered functions `DATE_ADDDAYSTODATE`, `DATE_ADDMONTHSTODATE`, and `DATE_ADDYEARSTODATE` that work but I cannot locate any documentation:

```
SELECT DATE_ADDDAYSTODATE(1, '2022-01-01'),
       DATE_ADDMONTHSTODATE(1, '2022-01-01'),
       DATE_ADDYEARSTODATE(1, '2022-01-01');
```

Output:

[image]

In general:

```
SELECT DATE_ADD<time_part>STODATE(...),
       DATE_ADD<time_part>STOTIMESTAMP(...)
```

They seems to be alias/equivalent of [DATEADD](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/dateadd.html) `DATEADD(<time_part>, 1, '2022-01-01)`. They are not disoverable using `SHOW FUNCTIONS`:

```
SHOW BUILTIN FUNCTIONS LIKE 'DATE%';
```

[image]

I am searching for a documentation entry or explanation why we cannot list them using `SHOW FUNCTIONS` command.